# perf_events over ssh (osx -> linux) freezing and unresponsive

Tags: linux, terminal, osx, perf

I'm using linux perf_events and sometimes am having trouble with the `perf report` (which is a terminal application) view freezing up. I'm interacting with a remote linux server which is running perf using a terminal window on OSX (with `$TERM` set to `xterm-256color`).

I say "sometimes am having trouble" because when I run a perf report on a short-running program, such as `ls` it works just fine. But, when I run a longer-running parallel MPI program, when I run `perf report` I see the initial screen but the terminal becomes unresponsive and I have to close the window. In both cases `perf record` seems to work just fine; the problem shows up when I use `perf report`. I see two white cursors or "white blocks" off to the right side of the screen when this happens, jumping up and down vertically.

I think there's some sort of terminal issue.

I'm `ssh`ing to the remote server with the `-X` and `-Y` options, and am running XQuartz on OSX.

Can anyone help me get `perf report` running remotely over ssh?

Comment: Actually linux-tools (on Debian at least) does not use ncurses, but uses slang.

Comment: I tried to add & at the end of command and it worked , perf report > mylog.txt &